# can't zip files from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zip

I try to zip files, I used the example from https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-create-a-zip-archive-from-multiple-files-or-directory/

```
with ZipFile('sample2.zip', 'w') as zipObj2:

   # Add multiple files to the zip
   zipObj2.write('sample_file.csv')
```

`sample2.zip` is created, but it is empty. Of course that the `csv` file exists and is not empty.

- I run this code from Jupyter Notebook

edit: I'm using relative paths -

```
input_dir = "../data/example/" 
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(input_dir, 'f.zip'), 'a') as zipObj2: 
zipObj2.write(os.path.join(input_dir, 'f.tif'))
```

Comment: Are you sure `sample_file.csv` is in the same folder where `sample2.zip` is created?

Comment: yes, the folder contains sample_file.csv and the output file (sample2.zip) is saved to that same location

Comment: You code works fine for me using Py2.7, 3.6 and 3.8

Comment: does it work from Jupyter Notebook as well? any chance it causes the problem?

Comment: @obart I would also check write permission on the folder and trustability of the notebook from `File / Trust Notebook`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I just tested using Jupyter with Python 3.7 and your code worked as expected.

Comment: input_dir = "../data/example/"
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(input_dir, 'f.zip'), 'a') as zipObj2:
    zipObj2.write(os.path.join(input_dir, 'f.tif'))
--
sorry for not updating the original question. any chance that using the relative paths somehow causes some problem? (the files do exist in this location)

Comment: @Giova
I tried that, still does not work

Answer (score 2):

you tried to close zip file to save ?

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('sample2.zip', 'w') as zipObj2:
   zipObj2.write('sample_file.csv')
   zipObj2.close()
```

Comment: what's the purpose of the `with` statement?

Comment: don't know completely,  but surely know that it is used to create, read and overwrite files. I checked the tutorial of zipfile

Comment: basically it allows automatic close call on objects of classes supporting it; so it's unuseful in the above code. Depending on the implementation of dunder exit it may even be dangerous.

Comment: You might true. it may be because depend on zipfile's version, I tried the piece of code on my jupyter notebook wihout closing the zip file and it returned an empty zip file. When I closed it, I reached my goal

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, but if I'm correct it sounds like you're trying to place multiple CSV files within a single zipped file? If so, this is what you're looking for:

```
#initiate files variable that contains the directory from which you wish to zip csv files
files=[f for f in os.listdir("./your_directory") if f.endswith('.csv')]

#initalize empty DataFrame 
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

#iterate through the files variable and concatenate them to all_data 
for file in files:
df = pd.read_csv('./your_directory' + file)
all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df])
```

Then call your new DataFrame(all_data) to verify that contents were transferred.

Comment: I'm trying to actually create a new .zip file that contains the csv files

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet allows you to zip only specific file types

```
import os import shutil from unittest.mock import patch

_os_path_isfile = os.path.isfile


def accept(path):
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path)
    if file_extension not in [".py", ".ipynb"]:
        return False
    print("archiving %r" % path)
    return _os_path_isfile(path)



with patch("os.path.isfile", side_effect=accept):
    shutil.make_archive("archive_file_name", "zip", ".")
```